# How to limit using memory by Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx, freebsd

My system is

```
% uname -or
FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p2
```

Sphinx version is

```
% searchd --help
Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)
```

Sphinx configuration:

```
index content_rt_template : common_template
{
    type              = rt
    rt_mem_limit      = 128M              # 128M only...

    rt_field          = text
    rt_attr_string    = text
    rt_field          = title
    rt_attr_string    = title
    rt_field          = url
    rt_attr_string    = url
    rt_attr_bigint    = item_id
    rt_attr_uint      = source_id
    rt_attr_timestamp = published_date
    rt_attr_timestamp = created_date
}

common {
    lemmatizer_base   = /path/to/sphinx/
}

indexer
{
    mem_limit         = 128M              # 128M only...
}


index content_rt_from_20170501_to_20170601 : content_rt_template
{
    path              = /path/to/sphinx/data/2017/content_rt_from_20170501_to_20170601
}

index content_rt_from_20170601_to_20170701 : content_rt_template
{
    path              = /path/to/sphinx/data/2017/content_rt_from_20170601_to_20170701
}

index content_rt_from_20171201_to_20180101 : content_rt_template
{
    path              = /path/to/sphinx/data/2017/content_rt_from_20171201_to_20180101
}

index content2017
{
    type              = distributed
    local             = content_rt_from_20170501_to_20170601
    local             = content_rt_from_20170601_to_20170701
    local             = content_rt_from_20171201_to_20180101
}

searchd
{
    listen            = 127.0.0.1:9417
    listen            = 9317:mysql41
    log               = /path/to/sphinx/log/searchd_2017.log
    query_log         = /path/to/sphinx/log/query_2017.log
    read_timeout      = 60
    max_children      = 30
    pid_file          = /path/to/sphinx/pid/searchd2017.pid
    seamless_rotate   = 0
    preopen_indexes   = 0
    unlink_old        = 1
    workers           = threads # for RT to work
    binlog_path       = /path/to/sphinx/data/2017/
}
```

Used memory before starting Sphinx:

```
Mem[|||||||||                     5.33G/40.0G]
Swp[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||3.35G/4.00G]
```

Log on Sphinx start:

```
% ./start.sh
Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)
Copyright (c) 2001-2016, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/path/to/sphinx/conf/content2017.conf'...
listening on 127.0.0.1:9417
listening on all interfaces, port=9317
WARNING: index 'common_template': key 'path' not found - NOT SERVING
WARNING: index 'content_rt_template': path must be specified - NOT SERVING
WARNING: failed to init process shared rwlock: process shared rwlock is not supported by FreeBSD; ALTER disabled
precaching index 'content_rt_from_20170501_to_20170601'
WARNING: failed to init process shared rwlock: process shared rwlock is not supported by FreeBSD; ALTER disabled
precaching index 'content_rt_from_20170601_to_20170701'
WARNING: failed to init process shared rwlock: process shared rwlock is not supported by FreeBSD; ALTER disabled
precaching index 'content_rt_from_20171201_to_20180101'
precached 3 indexes in 6.520 sec
Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)
Copyright (c) 2001-2016, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/path/to/sphinx/conf/content_dist.conf'...
listening on 127.0.0.1:9312
listening on all interfaces, port=9306
WARNING: index 'common_template': key 'path' not found - NOT SERVING
WARNING: index 'content_rt_template': path must be specified - NOT SERVING
WARNING: failed to init process shared rwlock: process shared rwlock is not supported by FreeBSD; ALTER disabled
precaching index 'content_snippet'
precached 1 indexes in 0.064 sec
```

Used memory after Sphinx started:

```
Mem[|||||||||||||||               11.6G/40.0G]
Swp[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||3.34G/4.00G]
```

Sphinx use about 6G. But according to `mem_limit` and `rt_mem_limit` must use not more than 128 * 3 = 384M.

What may be reason of using lot of memory?

Maybe reason in this warning?

> WARNING: failed to init process shared rwlock: process shared rwlock

**UPD**

I has tryed it on Ubuntu 16.04 and situation is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rt_mem_limit only limits the size of the ram chunk itself. Any disk chunks will use their own memory.

Typically its attributes that compose the biggest part , as by default, all are held in memory. Can cut down memory with http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-ondisk-attrs

Answer (score 0):

With option

```
ondisk_attrs = pool
```

RT index use not many RAM.